# How to implement promises in vanilla javascript to wait for transitions to complete?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise, setinterval

I am having difficulty iterating through a list of items and fading them in and out via vanilla javascript. Let's say I have a list of strings ["cat", "ball", "bat", "mouse"].

I want to loop through these items and display them one by one. For instance, first I need to display "cat" and then proceed to displaying "bat". In order to do this, I must first wait until "cat" is faded in, wait for it fade out, and then display "bat." Currently, I'm just using a for loop, the loop is going straight to the end of the list "mouse" and not waiting for the other elements to finish fading in and out.

To fix this, I am aware I need to use asynchronous programming, callbacks, promise API, etc, but I haven't really worked too much with these so I don't know how to implement this solution. Any help or clarity on how to use asynchronous programming alongside "setInterval()" is greatly appreciated.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var textarr = ["cat", "ball", "bat", "mouse"]
for(let i=0; i<textarr.length; i++){
  var text_item = document.getElementById('text_item');
  text_item.style.opacity = 0;
  text_item.innerHTML = textarr[i];
  // problem lies here; this is skipping to end of the list (mouse)
  fadeIn(text_item);
}

//function borrowed from stack overflow to fadeIn elements

function fadeIn(element) {
    var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    element.style.display = 'block';
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op >= 1){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets in your question.

Comment: Start without promises. Use only  `setTimeout` (or a transition event handler, depending on how the animation is coded) and callbacks. Use a recursive approach to run through the list. Once you got those basics, learn about promises.

Comment: It depends on how you are doing the transition.

Comment: Rather than promises, you may be able to do this with simple transition end event handlers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Comment: I apologize for the lack of code snippets - I've edited the question to include them. Thanks!

Comment: You would be better off with a queue and animation could be done with CSS wihtout JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing the `transitionend` event that @RwwL mentioned in the comments:

```js
let display = document.getElementById('display');
const animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse'];
let i = 0;

display.addEventListener('transitionend', function(event) {
  if (i < animals.length) {
    if (!display.classList.contains('fadeIn')) {
      display.innerHTML = animals[i++];
    }
    display.classList.toggle('fadeIn');
  }
}, false);

// Set timeout, otherwise the transition won't take effect (there are ways around this)
setTimeout(() => {
  display.classList.toggle('fadeIn');
}, 1000);
```

```css
#display {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: color 1s ease-in;
}

#display.fadeIn {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">Animal Names Here</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use a queue where the timer picks the item from the list and than does the action. In this case I coded it with CSS transitions to do the simple fade.

```js
// Made it a function so you could use 
// it more than once on same page
function changeText (arr, elem, startIndex) {
  // holds active slide
  let current = startIndex || 0
  // Called when we what to show the current word
  const update = function () {
    // set the word on the page
    elem.innerHTML = arr[current]
    // Add the class to start transition
    elem.classList.add('fadeIn')
    // How long you want the word to stay on the screen
    // When timer executes it calls function to reverse
    // the annimation
    window.setTimeout(next, 3000)  // 3 seconds
  }
  // Called to do the reverse animation and update the step
  const next = function () {  
    // remove the class so goes back to zero
    elem.classList.remove('fadeIn')
    // update what slide we are on
    current++
    // If we are over the limit, than restart
    if (current===arr.length) {
      current = 0  // back to first slide
    }
    // How long do you want for the fade out transition to
    // take to execute. 
    window.setTimeout(update, 300);  // 300 milliseconds
  }
  // initialize it so first word shows up
  update();
}

var textarr = ["cat", "ball", "bat", "mouse"]
changeText(textarr, document.querySelector('.text1'))

changeText(textarr, document.querySelector('.text2'), 3)
```

```css
.text {
  opacity: 0;  
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<h1>One</h1>
<div class="text text1"></div>
<h2>Another one</h2>
<div class="text text2"></div>
```