# How to chain CSS animations using Promise?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, css-animations, es6-promise

I'm trying to figure out how `Promise` works and to make one CSS animation to run after another. But they run simultaneously...

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04v1fx95/)

```
let move_boxes = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        resolve ('boxes moved!')
    })
};
let move_box_one = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        resolve (document.getElementById('div_two').style.animation = 'move 3s forwards')
        console.log('box one moved!')   
    })

}
let move_box_two = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        resolve (document.getElementById('div_one').style.animation = 'move 3s forwards')
        console.log('box two moved!')       
    })
}

move_boxes().then(() => {
    return move_box_one();
}).then(() => {
    return move_box_two();
});
```

Comment: You are chaining your promise-returning function calls together correctly. But the functions resolve their returned promises immediately, without waiting for the animation to finish!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316852/how-to-implement-promises-in-vanilla-javascript-to-wait-for-transitions-to-compl/54317538#54317538

Comment: Promises don't make anything asynchronous. They're for *managing* asynchronous behavior in other APIs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In contrary to the answers posted, I would discourage using `window.setTimeout`, because it does not guarantee that the timers are in sync with the animation end events, which sometimes are offloaded to the GPU. If you want to be extra sure, **you should be listening to the [`animationend` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event)**, and resolving it in the callback itself, i.e.:

```
let move_box_one = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const el = document.getElementById('div_one');
    const onAnimationEndCb = () => {
      el.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEndCb);
      resolve();
    }

    el.addEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEndCb)
    el.style.animation = 'move 3s forwards';
  });
}
```

Even better, is that since you're writing somewhat duplicated logic for both boxes, you can abstract all that into a generic function that returns a promise:

```
// We can declare a generic helper method for one-time animationend listening
let onceAnimationEnd = (el, animation) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const onAnimationEndCb = () => {
      el.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEndCb);
      resolve();
    }
    el.addEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEndCb)
    el.style.animation = animation;
  });
}

let move_box_one = async () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('div_one');
  await onceAnimationEnd(el, 'move 3s forwards');
}
let move_box_two = async () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('div_two');
  await onceAnimationEnd(el, 'move 3s forwards');
}
```

Also, your `move_boxes` function is a little convoluted. If you want to run the individual box-moving animations asynchronous, declare it as an async method and simply await individual box moving function calls, i.e.:

```
let move_boxes = async () => {
  await move_box_one();
  await move_box_two();
}
move_boxes().then(() => console.log('boxes moved'));
```

See proof-of-concept example (or you can see it from [this JSFiddle that I've forked](https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/3nozrh0v/) from your original one):

```js
// We can declare a generic helper method for one-time animationend listening
let onceAnimationEnd = (el, animation) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const onAnimationEndCb = () => {
      el.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEndCb);
      resolve();
    }
    el.addEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEndCb)
    el.style.animation = animation;
  });
}

let move_box_one = async () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('div_one');
  await onceAnimationEnd(el, 'move 3s forwards');
}
let move_box_two = async () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('div_two');
  await onceAnimationEnd(el, 'move 3s forwards');
}

let move_boxes = async () => {
  await move_box_one();
  await move_box_two();
}
move_boxes().then(() => console.log('boxes moved'));
```

```css
#div_one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 10px solid red;
}

#div_two {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 10px solid blue;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(300px);
  }
}

@keyframes down {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div_one"></div>
<div id="div_two"></div>
```

Comment: You might want to update this answer [to handle the `animationcancel` event too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationcancel_event) (perhaps by invoking `reject`?).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to only resolve the promise when you know that the corresponding animation event completed.

You can use the [`animationend`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp) event for that, which is more appropriate than using `setTimeout` with the expected duration.

It will also be useful to create one utility function for creating a promise for that, and then to reuse that for whichever element and whichever animation description:

```js
const promiseAnimation = (elem, animation) => new Promise(resolve => {
    elem.style.animation = animation;
    elem.addEventListener("animationend", resolve);
});

const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

const moveBoxOne = () => promiseAnimation($("#div_one"), "move 3s forwards");
const moveBoxTwo = () => promiseAnimation($("#div_two"), "move 3s forwards");


Promise.resolve()
    .then(moveBoxOne)
    .then(() => console.log("one has moved"))
    .then(moveBoxTwo)
    .then(() => console.log("two has moved"))
```

```css
div { display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid; }
@keyframes move {
  from {margin-left: 0px;}
  to {margin-left: 100px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="div_one">div_one</div><br>
<div id="div_two">div_two</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to wait for animation to complete, Here is a working code,

```
    let move_boxes = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        resolve ('boxes moved!')
    })
};
let move_box_one = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        document.getElementById('div_two').style.animation = 'move 3s forwards';
        setTimeout(()=> resolve(), 3000);   
    })

}
let move_box_two = () => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        document.getElementById('div_one').style.animation = 'move 3s forwards';
        setTimeout(()=> resolve(), 3000);
    })
}

move_boxes().then(() => {
    return move_box_one();
}).then(() => {
    return move_box_two();
});
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bu96cxak/

Answer (score -1):

Promise does not mean it will be asynchronous. Since the resolve is instant, so most likely they run in same time. If you want to delay, u can create a delay in a call using setTimeout.

```
const delay = (dl) => new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(r, dl)
})

let move_box_one = () => {
    document.getElementById('div_two').style.animation = 'move 3s forwards'
    console.log('box one moved!') 

}
let move_box_two = () => {
    document.getElementById('div_one').style.animation = 'move 3s forwards'
    console.log('box two moved!')       
}

(async function() {
    move_box_one()
    await delay(200)
    move_box_two()
})()
```