# Chaining Animista CSS animations with Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, promise, css-animations, animista

I searched for how to chain Animista CSS animations with JavaScript to slide out a tab and slide in a new one. I couldn't find anything but I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683529/how-to-chain-css-animations-using-promise) on chaining animations using Promises.

Comment: https://animejs.com/  hv u looked into this ?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code to slide in and out a container for use in tabs.

```js
// We can declare a generic helper method for one-time animationend listening
let hideElement = (el, animation) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const onAnimationEndCb = () => {
        el.classList.remove('active', animation);
      el.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEndCb);
      resolve();
    }
    el.classList.add(animation);
    el.addEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEndCb)
  });
}

let showElement = (el, animation) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const onAnimationEndCb = () => {
      el.classList.remove(animation);
      el.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEndCb);
      resolve();
    }
    el.classList.add('active', animation);
    el.addEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEndCb)
  });
}

let hide_box_one = async () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('div_one');
  await hideElement(el, 'slide-out-top');
}
let show_box_two = async () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('div_two');
  await showElement(el, 'slide-in-top');
}
let hide_box_two = async () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('div_two');
  await hideElement(el, 'slide-out-top');
}
let show_box_one = async () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('div_one');
  await showElement(el, 'slide-in-top');
}

let change_tabs = async () => {
  await hide_box_one();
  await show_box_two();
  await hide_box_two();
  await show_box_one();
  await hide_box_one();
  await show_box_two();
  await hide_box_two();
  await show_box_one();
  await hide_box_one();
  await show_box_two();
  await hide_box_two();
  await show_box_one();
}

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
    change_tabs().then(() => console.log('tabs changed'));
};
```

```css
#div_one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  display: none;
}
#div_one.active{
  display:block;
}

#div_two {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  display: none;
}
#div_two.active{
  display:block;
}
#btn{
  margin-top:10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.slide-in-top {
    -webkit-animation: slide-in-top 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
            animation: slide-in-top 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}
  
.slide-out-top {
    -webkit-animation: slide-out-top 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
            animation: slide-out-top 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}
  
/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-8-22 19:10:58
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation slide-in-top
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
@-webkit-keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-in-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-out-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-out-top {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div_one" class="active"></div>
<div id="div_two"></div>
<button id="btn" type="button">Next Tab</button>
```

`enter code here`