# Execute functions in order inside "if" statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, css-animations

I have some functions

```
function growSeparator() {
    $('.applications-worth-module__separator').addClass('applications-worth-module__separator--active');
}
function reachPkt1() {
    $('.point-1-separator').addClass('point-separator--pkt1_active');
}
function reachPkt2() {
    $('.point-2-separator').addClass('point-separator--pkt2_active');
}
function reachPkt3() {
    $('.point-3-separator').addClass('point-separator--pkt3_active');
}
function reachPkt4() {
    $('.point-4-separator').addClass('point-separator--pkt4_active');
}
```

Every one of them adds css class with keyframes animation inside. I try to execute a function when element reaches middle screen. I'm using getBoundingClientRect to do it.

```
var pkt1 = document.querySelector(".point-1__container");
var pkt2 = document.querySelector(".point-2__container");
var pkt3 = document.querySelector(".point-3__container");
var pkt4 = document.querySelector(".point-4__container");

window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
   if (pkt1.getBoundingClientRect().top < window.innerHeight/2) {
        growSeparator();
   }
   if (pkt1.getBoundingClientRect().top < (window.innerHeight/2)) {
        reachPkt1(); 
   }
   if (pkt2.getBoundingClientRect().top < (window.innerHeight/2)) {
        reachPkt2();
   }
   if (pkt3.getBoundingClientRect().top < (window.innerHeight/2)) {
        reachPkt3();
   }
   if (pkt4.getBoundingClientRect().top < (window.innerHeight/2)) {
        reachPkt4();
   }
})
```

The problem is - when I scroll to the last element, every function fires at the same time, not one by one. I tried to use "animationend" and "transitionend" event, but it works only for one element and for other four - not.

How can I achieve this effect, when I scroll to the last element (.point-4__container) all of my previous functions execute one after another?

Thanks.

Comment: does this imply that if you would scroll to the third point u would want function 1,2 and 3 run? actualy your code does exactly what you want it to do but it doesnt respect the duration of the animation, how long is it?

Comment: @johnSmith duration of every animation is exacly 1 second. If I scroll to the third point I want function 1,2 and 3 to run, but I want that every function will wait for previous function to finish. 

But wait... I realised just now that the problem isn't with functions, but keyframes itself - functions fires in the correct order, but every animation fires one after another but very quickly after the previous one...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to chain CSS animations using Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683529/how-to-chain-css-animations-using-promise)

Comment: you could apply one of the solutions mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921275/is-it-possible-to-chain-settimeout-functions-in-javascript